STM32F103 Series uC can't be programmed with Clone ST-Link V2
I designed a PCB with an STM32F103 uC placed on it. But I can't reach it with the STM32 Programmer.
I bought a STLINK-V2 Mini for that (amazon china clone, so I am not sure if maybe this is the problem...).

It detects the clone I think, but I only got 2.4V at my uC. I measured that on the board and I am having 3.3V there.

This is the Schematic for my board.
I also tried to pull NRST Low during Power up and then tried to connect, but this is also not working.
Any Ideas?

You have a clone. You can't expect it to work reliably with program made by ST and expecting to see a proper non-clone ST-Link. The clone product may have too old firmware to be compatible with the PC software, and it may be impossible to update the firmware of the clone. I believe the 15 dollar price difference between a clone and original product is not worth the trouble of investigating the problems that may come with it. Also you don't say how you connect to it - do you have ground wire too, and real ST-link requires 3V supply from the target board. You need to know how your clone works.

Given the price of the original ST-Link, just having to deal with the problem - making sure it doesn't work, trying to diagnose it, then asking the question - has cost you more than buying the original in the first place. Even if you "paid yourself" the lowest wage in your area. Basically, ST-Link clones are a net loss to most people. Only the sellers and Amazon make money on them. The users lose out.

I wired correctly and actually everything was setup correct.
I found my misstake. SWD should be PA13. I solderd a cable to it and now I can connect.
